# Typescript not inferring the type as string even after type checking

Tags: node.js, typescript

```
const { AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_REGION } = process.env;

if (!AWS_ACCESS_KEY || !AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY || !AWS_REGION) {
  throw new Error("AWS credentials not found");
}

export { AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_REGION };
```

type of the constants at the beginning of the file is `string | undefined` but even after checking it exists the exported constants still have the type as `string | undefined`

I know i can use type assertion or add a declaration file. But i want to know why it happens like this.

Comment: I'm not sure why exports don't reflect control flow narrowing (still researching).  You could work around it the same way as in [ms/TS#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) and copy narrowed results to new variables and export those, as shown [in this codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-xm22vn?file=/lib.ts), but you're not asking for workarounds, right?  The question as asked is "why does this happen", and right now I'm not sure how to get an authoritative answer without finding or filing a github issue.  Will update later.

Comment: Well, I still haven't found anything canonical.  Multiple answers here assert that it doesn't work because the type system doesn't track control flow (which is either false or maybe just worded weirdly?) but don't provide sources for these assertions so I don't know where they got it from.  Maybe I'll file a github issue (or you could if you want).  How do you want to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why TypeScript is not inferring the type as string even after type checking is because the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and `AWS_REGION` variables are declared as `string | undefined`.

This means that they can be either a string or undefined. When you check if they exist, you are only narrowing the type to string. However, the TypeScript type checker cannot be sure that the variables will actually be assigned a string value. Therefore, the exported constants still have the type as `string | undefined`.

There are a few ways to fix this. One way is to use type assertion. For example, you could do the following:

```
const { AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_REGION } = process.env;

if (!AWS_ACCESS_KEY || !AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY || !AWS_REGION) {
  throw new Error("AWS credentials not found");
}

export {
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY as string,
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as string,
  AWS_REGION as string,
};
```

This will tell TypeScript that the exported constants are definitely strings, even though they are declared as `string | undefined`.

Another way to fix this is to add a declaration file. A declaration file is a file that tells TypeScript the types of the variables and functions in your code. You can use a declaration file to specify that the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and `AWS_REGION` variables are always strings.

Here is an example of a declaration file that you could use:

```
declare const AWS_ACCESS_KEY: string;
declare const AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: string;
declare const AWS_REGION: string;
```

Once you have added a declaration file, TypeScript will be able to infer the type of the exported constants as a string.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Do you have any source for this? I'd love to see something authoritative that says that control flow analysis doesn't affect exports the way it affects function returns. Right now this just looks like an assertion about behavior (and some of it is suspect; saying "the TypeScript type checker cannot be sure that the variables will actually be assigned a string value" doesn't explain the difference between the code as presented and [this code](https://tsplay.dev/w2kOzN)) without links to source documents.